# Get Max value from String Column containing alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, max

I have table containing multiple columns and I want to get maximum value from invoice number which consists of alphanumeric value like **"AR564"**. I know I should have numeric column to make this happen but now I have a lot of data and it is difficult to change basic things. So I want to solve problem of getting **"AR999"** as maximum instead of **"AR1000"**. I have tried doing

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(invoice_number, 4, length(invoice_number)-2) AS UNSIGNED)) 
FROM table
```

but getting following error.

```
IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_Fail (0x80004005)
```

I am using Microsoft Access database and please someone tell me what is the purpose of **"4"** in above sql statement.

Comment: MS Access does not have CAST, unless you have an SQL server back-end. Try `clng(mid(invoice_number,3))`  Note that MAX is very, very unsafe for a number that means something. I recommend that you use a small table that can be locked to get the next value. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11950647/2548

Comment: thanks it worked. Please tell me what does 3 mean in above expression?

Comment: It is the start position. https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php