# Reset identity column in MS access database

Tags: database, ms-access

Currently i am trying to reset an identity column in my MS access database by using following command but it is not working.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('my_table', RESEED, 1)
```

Error Message :

```
Invalid SQL Statement ; expected "Delete","insert","procedure","select" or "update"
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHECKIDENT` works on SQL Server only. Here is a link to an explanation how to do it in Access: [How to restart counting from 1 after erasing table in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416619/how-to-start-counting-from-1-after-erase-table-in-access)