# How to reset AutoIncrement field from Access Database

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to reset the Autoincrement field of a particular field. 
The reason because it gets a count that auto populates in a case number. But when it hits mindnight 12/31/2013 11:59:00 PM I want to autoincrement to start again from zero.

This is some code I have.
This code is on Form1 and I get the value of the ID2 from Form2 to keep the case number consistant only when they hit at Field1 by using the Double Click

```
Private Sub Field1_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Docmd.OpenForm "Form2",,,,acFormAdd,acHidden
    Me.Field1 = Format(Date, "YY") & "-" & Format(Forms!Form2!ID2, "0000")
    Me.Field2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Maybe someone has a different approach. For counting upwards.
Now my problem I have is that when I reach "12/31/13 11:59:00 PM" I want that autoincrement to reset itself back to 1 to start a brand new case number. with the format provided.
Right know it works fine  the format they see is YY-0001 in order words 13-0001 case number example. I have the following code that I think It should work for reseting the autoincrement. probably someone has a better approach then this.
My code.

```
Private Sub Field1_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Text5 > "12:/31/2013 11:59:00 PM" Then
        DoCmd. DeleteObject acTable, "Table2"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE Table2 ([ID2] AUTOINCREMENT, [Field1] text (255))"
    end if
```

The problem I have how do I manage from changing what happens if they dont press the number how do I force it to change.
I have the text5 on a timer
timer intervals every 1000 milliseconds which is one second
the code that runs for the timer is

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me.Text5 = Now()
End Sub
```

I have two problems what happends if they never need to press how do I validate so it can delete the table and create a new table once it works the autoincrement will refresh the only problem is that how do i force it that it will do it on its own.

Comment: I tried and it deletes the table and adds a new one and it gives me a brand new record I kind of taught outside the box'

Comment: But I want a better suggestion from someone if they have a better code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere ALTER COLUMN FieldNameHere COUNTER(1,1)"
```

Comment: Hey Johny but I want the column to reset when the new year comes. How could I do that.

Comment: You'd have to run it manually when the new year comes.  Or put in the Open Form event to check the date, and if it's a new year then run the code.

Comment: For those who come here from Google there is good discussion at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416619

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

1. Remove the Primary Key from the field
2. Delete the field
3. Make a new field exactly as the one you deleted
4. It's done

More details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kni5kFzlPk
Regards.