# Reset AUTO_INCREMENT in PHP on MDB ACCESS database

Tags: php, ms-access, auto-increment

For a demo purpose, I need after empty all tables in my ACCESS format "database.mdb" using PHP and then reset all IDs AUTO_INCREMENT to 1, but i've problems with resetting PRIMARY KEYS.

It's important i've do all with PHP script.

I tried with:

```
/* ConnString verso il database da compattare */
$oldConn="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
$oldConn.="Data Source=".$path.$olddb.";";
$oldConn.="Jet OLEDB:Database Password=$oldpass ;";

/* ConnString verso il nuovo database (compattato) */
$newConn="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
$newConn.="Data Source=".$path.$newdb.";";
$newConn.="Jet OLEDB:Database Password=$newpass ;";    
$je=new COM("JRO.JetEngine") or die("Compact failed");
    $je->CompactDatabase($oldConn,$newConn) ;
    $je->Release() ;
    $je= null ;
```

but i get an error with CompactDatabase().

I also tried with PDO connection and:

```
$pdo->exec("ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
```

or

```
$s = $pdo->prepare("ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN ID INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT");
```

but i get: `Syntax error or access violation`

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: how is this code connected to PDO?

Comment: sorry i connect with JRO, not PDO. code updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset AutoIncrement field from Access Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318594/how-to-reset-autoincrement-field-from-access-database)

Comment: I need to do that in PHP script. Not with ASP and not with Microsoft Office Access executable.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn COUNTER(1,1)
```

Comment: No success. I get error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -1046 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] - ID is part of one or more relations. ....I tried delete relationsship of ID with other tables....but same error...

Comment: Hmm I "think" it may be because a PDO returns something and a DDL alter statement does not?