# Enable/Disable AutoIncrement in Access2010/2013

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010, oledb

I want to programmatically disable and then enable `AutoIncrement` property for the `ID` column in my `Access` database.

I used `Columns[i].AutoIncrement` to turn on/off this property and updated the table .. but it didn't work!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416619/how-to-restart-counting-from-1-after-erasing-table-in-ms-access

Comment: He is not asking how to reset the auto increment field so this is not a duplicate of this question. He is asking how to change the column type

Comment: @TedoG. Also I see that you edited the tags to change C# to vba, an remove SQL. This is also completely false. The user is using C# and SQL over an MS Access database using OLEDB tech, so he properly tagged his question.

Comment: yes, I've been hardly mistaken, my apologies.