# In database AutoIncrease column. What if value reached maximum value

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, ms-access

I am developing an Access database application. This app have huge amount of changes (Added rows) every minute. All changes saved in a table which has an 'ID' Auto increase column (Starts from 0 ). At some point the 'ID' value will reach max. allowed value (Integer.MaxValue I think or whatever). how can I add new rows after this?

Note: When Adding rows I also remove previous rows. So, the total table rows count won't be greater than 100 rows, but 'ID' column won't repeat its values or restart counting from 0 again.

Comment: Even with a regular 32bit Autonumber column, it would last 2^31 / (60*24*365) = **4085 years** with one record per minute. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Large Number (bigint)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/03/06/new-in-access-2016-large-number-bigint-support/) instead and [Stop Worrying About Exhausting Bigints](http://improve.dk/stop-worrying-about-exhausting-bigints/).

Comment: This is valid only for Access 2016 (Office 365).  This is clear on the linked page, but it is best to include this information with the SO answer.  The page also does not mention AutoNumber fields.  I don't have Access 2016, so can you verify this solution works with AutoNumber?

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform a [identity reseed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416619/how-to-restart-counting-from-1-after-erasing-table-in-ms-access) will explain how to do that in access db.

Comment: Thank you very much, helpful.